# Django Group by query

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-orm

I have a table with the following columns:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    avg_value=models.CharField('Avg Value',)
    sys_timestamp = models.IntegerField('SYS Timestamp')
```

Now i want to do this mysql query:

```
select max(id), avg_value, sys_timestamp from Table1 group by sys_timestamp order by id desc limit 10;
```

I only want max_id and avg_value and sys_timestamp in the result 
If possible with only sys_timestamp and avg_value example `[[1404385800L,-34],[1404385500L,-45].............]`
with the group_by to only sys_timestamp using Django ORM.

I have tried the following but failed to get the desired result.

```
Table1.objects.values_list('sys_timestamp','avg_value').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('-id')[:10]
```

AND

IF I do:

```
    print (Table1.objects.values_list('sys_timestamp','avg_value').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('-id')[:10]).query

SELECT Table1.sys_timestamp, Table1.avg_value, MAX(Table1.id) AS max_id FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.sys_timestamp, Table1.avg_value ORDER BY Table1.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

The order_by is with `sys_timestamp` and `avg_value` which is not required.

IF I do :

```
(PerformanceService.objects.only('avg_value','sys_timestamp').values('sys_timestamp').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('-id')[:6]).query

SELECT Table1.sys_timestamp, MAX(Table1.id) AS max_id FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.sys_timestamp ORDER BY Table1.id DESC LIMIT 6
```

This return:

```
[{'sys_timestamp': 1404385800L, 'max_id': 7380}, {'sys_timestamp': 1404385500L, 'max_id': 7370}, {'sys_timestamp': 1404385200L, 'max_id': 7360}.............]
```

But requirement is

```
[{'sys_timestamp': 1404385800L, 'max_id': 7380, avg_value:-34}, {'sys_timestamp': 1404385500L, 'max_id': 7370, avg_value:-39}, {'sys_timestamp': 1404385200L, 'max_id': 7360, avg_value:-23}.............]
```

Any Idea . ?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you want to achieve this query:

> `select max(id), avg_value, sys_timestamp from Table1 group by sys_timestamp order by id desc limit 10;`

What you want is technically wrong. You can't use a column which is not in the GROUP BY clause, in your SELECT clause (there might be more than one `avg_value` associated with a `sys_timestamp`).

If you're sure there is only one `avg_value` for each `sys_timestamp`, you can go with this:

```
Table1.objects.values('sys_timestamp').annotate(max_id=Max('id'), avg_val=Max('avg_value')).order_by('-max_id')[:10]
```

Note that I used Max('avg_value') as a hack, that is equal to the only `avg_value` there is.